# mdPickers - unable to set date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, timezone

Well, I'm trying to use mdPicker for my date input.
So, here is what I'm getting from my database

```
2017-01-04T00:00:00+0000
```

So, everything I need is to set this date into mdPicker.

But it always shows 3rd, or 5th but not the 4th January, I have no idea what I need to do. Here is [codeopen](http://codepen.io/luninroman/pen/EZaXoV) example. My local timezone -0500. I was also trying to substract 1 day via moment.js, set timezone via Angular date filter, but no luck. I can't understand what I missed. Anyone?

Comment: The time is actually correct (in your codepen as well).  From the above sample `+0000` means UTC timezone.  EST is -5, which is correctly flagged as `2400` - `0500` = `1900`  -- so 7pm. The format above is standard [atom](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4287) format

Comment: @Lunin - On my side the date dispaly 4th January. My time Zone is IST. So, i think your code works fine but there is little problem with timezone.

Comment: The actual problem is that I'm getting the 3rd picked http://prntscr.com/drq77l, but not the 4th

Comment: trim date string to '2017-01-04' not works

Comment: little problem with timezone - I see, but what is the solution? I have no idea